# Targeting the first and last non-overflowing elements

Tags: jquery

In order to return the number of items overflowing to the right and to the left, I am looking for a way to target the first and last elements which are not overflowing (so i can count after and before them).

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 430px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 145px
}

a {
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <a>7</a>
    <a>8</a>
    <a>9</a>
    <a>10</a>
    <a>11</a>
    <a>12</a>
    <a>13</a>
    <a>14</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this exemple how would I target the first and last not overflowing elements (in this case 3 and 8) ?

I tried things like `$('.inner a:visible').last()` or `$('.inner a:visible:last')` but it wouldn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset()` and then `filter()` out elements that are less then 0 and larger that width of parent and take first and last element.

```js
var c = $('.container');
var cl = c.offset().left;

$('a').filter(function() {
  var xl = $(this).offset().left
  return (cl - xl) < 0
}).first().css('background', 'red')

$('a').filter(function() {
  var xl = $(this).offset().left
  return xl < (cl + c.width())
}).last().css('background', 'red')
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 430px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 145px;
}

a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <a>7</a>
    <a>8</a>
    <a>9</a>
    <a>10</a>
    <a>11</a>
    <a>12</a>
    <a>13</a>
    <a>14</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is getting me very close from what I'm trying to achieve. However my problem is that it doesn't seem to be working for the last element because it seems to calculate the offset from the whole document instead of the container (I believe). I'm not very familiar with this function but it seems to target the last element in a set width (the container's) starting from the left of the document. So the selected element will vary depending on where my container is on the page. Hopefully my explanation isn't too confusing, I can add a screenshot if needed.

Comment: Maybe you will also have to include width of `a` elements into calculation but you can figure that out.

Comment: Indeed this is working correctly, thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: @eloism Glad i could help.